# How to fetch tags information for all resources inside multiple Resource group for a given Azure account

Tags: python, cost-management

I have been trying to fetch the tags information of various Azure resources. I am able to find the appropriate way.

Till now I have been using Azure Cost Management API.

```
response = client.query.usage(
    scope=f"subscriptions/{azure_constant.subscription_id}",
    parameters={
        "dataset": {
        "granularity": "Daily",
        "aggregation": {
             "totalCostUSD": {
             "name": "CostUSD",
             "function": "Sum"}
},
    "grouping": [
    {
        "type": "Dimension",
        "name": "MeterCategory"
     },
     {
        "type": "Dimension",
        "name": "ResourceId"
      },
      {
        "type": "Tag",
        "name": ""
      }
]
},
```

I have been using this filter snippet till now.
Is there any other way I can get the customized Tags list done by my organization?